# Table row bottom border is not visble when converting html to MS word

Tags: html, css, html-table, ms-word

I am trying to convert some HTML content into MS word using the following approach but some of the styles that I am trying to set to the table rows(such as border-bottom) are not at all visible in the converted word document. Can someone help me out here?

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr style="border-bottom:2pt solid #AFAFAF">
               <td>One</td>
               <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border-bottom:2pt solid #AFAFAF">
               <td>One</td>
               <td>1</td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I even tried setting `style="mso-border-bottom-alt: solid #AFAFAF 2pt;"` which didn't work either. My requirement is very specific that I should have bottom border for every row.

Comment: Try to place the border to the `td`.

Comment: setting border-bottom to `td` is working but there is a tiny gap between the two <td>s border which I don't want. I want a straight line bottom-border under each row. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: setting `CELLSPACING="0"` to <table> did the trick along with applying border bottom to <td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Azu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12806767/azu), setting border-bottom to `<td>` instead of `<tr>` tags did the trick along with `cellspacing="0"` on `<table>`.

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <body>
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
               <td style="border-bottom:2pt solid #AFAFAF">One</td>
               <td style="border-bottom:2pt solid #AFAFAF">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="border-bottom:2pt solid #AFAFAF">One</td>
               <td  style="border-bottom:2pt solid #AFAFAF">1</td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```